# Why initialState doesn't show undefined fields but keeps null fields in redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-devtools

During development, I've found that fields in intialState gets eliminated from redux devtools as I declare them `undefined`. However, when I declare them as `null`, they appearing back again in the devtool. Why it is happening?

My initial state (`pending: undefined`)

```
const initialState = {
    data: null,
    pending: undefined,
    error: null
};
```

`pending` disappears from redux devtool:

[image: redux-devtool-undefined]

Same initial state (`pending: null`)

```
const initialState = {
    data: null,
    pending: null,
    error: null
};
```

`pending` appears back in redux devtool:

[image: redux-devtool-null]

2 Questions:

1. What pattern should I stick to? (i.e declaring fields as `null` or `undefined`)?
2. Is there any performance gain in terms of selecting parts of the store?

Answer (score 0):

`null` and `undefined` are two different values for a reason. Accessing a non assigned field on any js values (apart from those two ofc) will return `undefined`. So if you do:

```
var foo = {};
foo.bar = undefined;
```

You will get an object that *seems* to behave like its `bar` field is unassigned: except it is and you have `foo.hasOwnProperty("bar") === true`. It is confusing though. This is why to signify the *absence of value* `null` is used and and to signify *unassigned* value `undefined` is used. Interestingly this difference in behavior can be found when destructuring data structures:

```
var { foo = "bar" } = { foo: undefined }
```

and

```
var { foo = "bar" } = { foo: null }
```

will results in `foo === "bar"` in the former and `foo === null` in the latter.